# Xcode IB Stupid Warning

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

Once again Xcode IB frustrates developers with unnecessary warnings: I cannot seem to get remove this warning from my Xcode project.

[image]

When double clicking the warning it brings up my MainMenu.xib file but gives no reference to what is causing the issue. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I've stripped down much of my .xib for public viewing but still have the error with very few objects. You can find the file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2piuojr86dhlt9/MainMenu.xib?dl=0

Comment: can you make a stripped down sample project demoing this warning available somewheres?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I've tried isolating the problem by removing objects one by one, but the warning still appears until every object has been removed from the file

Comment: yep!  That's why I was hoping to see a sample project that demo's the problem, then I could try my hand at figuring it out for you (and everyone else :-).  Strip out everything but one object in the xib (where the warning still appears).

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I've shared a link to the file

Comment: thanks... I dropped the xib file into a sample Swift project but couldn't get any warning messages to appear in my Xcode 7 while building.  Still hunting though.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann hmm.. running the file in an obj-c Xcode 7 project and builds with the warning above

Comment: you should have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32896514/2557145

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a warning shown starting from Xcode 7 when UI elements like a label or table view column header use a font style or variation that is on available on older OS (and of course your project is still targeting them).

In my project a table view column header was using system font with "medium" font style variation instead of regular on a project targeting OS X 10.9+.

The weird thing is I had to restart Xcode as Interface Builder refused to change the style of the control. Possibly a small glitch of this early 7.0.1 Xcode version.

Anyway, either setting every control style to `Regular` or changing your project target to `10.11` should fix the warning.

Answer (score 0):

> Once again Xcode IB frustrates developers with unnecessary warnings.

Felt the same way about it too, until I saw how my typography differs in 10.10 compared to 10.11. One thing is true – the message is rubbish without pointing to a problematic storyboard item, see [P.S section of the post](https://medium.com/post-mortem/xcode-broad-system-font-weight-ed9af147333e) for a semi-workaround.

Current answer almost gets it, but problem is not with font styles being unavailable in older targets, it's with Xcode not handling them properly, see [full blog post](https://medium.com/post-mortem/xcode-broad-system-font-weight-ed9af147333e) for details.

If you want to keep your styles, use custom textfield with custom inspectable property. Open up identity inspector and set custom class to TextField, preferred font weight attribute will show up in attribute inspector, set the required value, build and enjoy the result.

```
import AppKit

@IBDesignable public class TextField: NSTextField
{
    @IBInspectable public var preferredFontWeight: Int = 0

    override public func awakeFromNib() {
        if #available(OSX 10.11, *) {
            return
        }

        guard
        let weight: Int = self.preferredFontWeight where weight > 0,
        let font: NSFont = self.font,
        let name: String = font.familyName,
        let manager: NSFontManager = NSFontManager.sharedFontManager() else {
            return
        }


        // Full details here – https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFontManager/convertWeight:ofFont:   
        //
        // 1 – ultralight
        // 2 – thin
        // 3 – light, extralight
        // 4 – book
        // 5 – regular, display
        // 6 – medium
        // 7 – demi, demibold
        // 8 – semi, semibold
        // 9 – bold
        // 10 – extra, extrabold
        // 11 – heavy
        // 12 – black
        // 13 – ultrablack
        // 14 – extrablack

        if let font: NSFont = manager.fontWithFamily(name, traits: manager.traitsOfFont(font), weight: weight, size: font.pointSize) {
            self.font = font
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't really care about the styles, use regular weight font for all text, it should solve the problem, see my earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36953773/458356) for available options.